# Graphql plugin for Neo4j returns data in iso-8859-1 encoding

Tags: neo4j, character-encoding, graphql

We have installed the GraphQl plugin (neo4j-graphql-3.3.0.0.jar) for Neo4j ddbb (3.3.3 community edition). When we query data using the GraphQl endpoint in Neo4j server we get the response encoded with iso-8859-1 (probably it is saved with the same encoding) instead of UTF-8.

Not sure if it is a misconfiguration in Neo4j server or in the GraphQl plugin, where can I find the relevant configuration settings regarding encoding?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which OS / Locale do you run on?

Comment: It happens under my Windows 10 local environment and also in our integration environment but not sure of the OS used there because I don't have access to it, I will ask for that information.

Comment: The integration environment is a CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)